# Powershell replace with double quotes and new line

Tags: powershell, replace, newline, double-quotes, single-quotes

I wanna replace something with double quotes, but also need a new line in the middle.
How can I do this? I tried all combinations, but it seems to me that a new line needs double quotes, is there any other way?

For example:

```
(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version="1.0">', 'version="1.0"> "`n `n" iNeedANewLineHere' | Set-Content -encoding UTF8 '.\output.xml'
```

This way it doesnt interpret the nl-commands as new lines, it prints everything as text, in cause of the single quotes... is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, but powershell can reformat an xml file and reencode it according to the tag in it as well:  `[xml]$xml = type file.xml; $xml.save("$pwd\file.xml")`

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes to enclose your string, and escape the inner double quotes as such:

```
(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version="1.0">', "version=`"1.0`"> `"`n `n`" iNeedANewLineHere" | Set-Content -encoding UTF8 '.\output.xml'
```

Or like this:

```
(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version="1.0">', "version=""1.0""> ""`n `n"" iNeedANewLineHere" | Set-Content -encoding UTF8 '.\output.xml'
```

If you are executing this from CMD you will need to escape any internal double quotes that you are trying to pass to PowerShell in CMD as they are passed. This should do that:

```
powershell -Command "(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version=^"1.0^">', ^"version=^"^"1.0^"^"> `n `n iNeedANewLineHere^" | Set-Content -encoding UTF8 '.\output.xml'"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So easy ;D   I had two double quotes too much, but this is the version I need  


```(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version="1.0">', "version=""1.0""> `n `n iNeedANewLineHere" | Set-Content -encoding UTF8 '.\output.xml' ```  

Single-quotes get a higher interpretation than double-quotes, right? Is there anything which is higher interpreted than single-quotes, i guessed this is the solution [makes it even more complex, i know, your way is the best way (; ]

Comment: I'm not sure what higher interpretation means, sorry. Hopefully [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1) can answer your question.

Comment: I meant higher level (of importance?) for single-quotes.  

Sincerely it's not working in CMD shell, it worked perfect in powershell but i need to run it in CMD shell.  After testing it seems to me, that it needs single-quotes, but how can i do a NewLine then?  

```powershell -Command "(gc 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\input.xml') -replace 'test', '"`n"success' | Set-Content -encoding UTF8 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\output.xml'```
This way, it doesnt work...

Comment: I have updated the answer to address your CMD issue.

Comment: Sorry, but still doesnt work... i get an error that the command is written wrong.

``powershell -Command "(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version=^"1.0"^>', ... `` 
I dont get an error like this, but in single-quotes it's interpreted as string by the shell, so now it's searching for version=^"1.0"^> 
which is wrong... :(

Comment: if I just do 
`` "(Get-Content '.\input.xml') -replace 'version', '`n success' ... `` 
i get version replaced by `` `n success`` 
which is not what i want... so i guess it's not working.. the command needs double-quotes for this and CMD-shell works only with single-quotes!?

Comment: ok, this works as a search string ``version=""1.0"" `` 
but i need ``version=""1.0""> `` getting replaced. 

and the new line is not made, `` '`n `n success' `` puts just a text string, so i get `` `n `n success ``

I guess it's not working with the two shells... in powershell only everything was fine, but the handover to CMD-shell causes problems with controll characters, i guess..

Comment: Why not make the powershell part a script, and then just call the script from CMD?